# Android aaptFriendlyManifestOutputDirectory=null

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I'm new to android studio and to android development in general. My application was building fine but now the Gradle fails to build with the following error message:

> Gradle tasks[:app:assembleDebug]
>
> null value in entry:aaptFriendlyManifestOutputDirectory=null

I haven't found any other threads encountering this issue and don't really know where to start to resolve it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow, I recommend you take the tour and check [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the .Gradle file resolved this issue for me!